# What is $\pi_1(C)$? . Is $\pi_1(C)$ constant or nonconstant function?

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $Y$ is  compact , the projection $\pi_1 : X \times  Y \to X$ is  a closed map

My attempt : I found the answer [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ealevine/411-S2019/HW8solutions.pdf) see the  question  no $3.26.7$

It is written that

> Let $C$ be any closed subset  of  $X \times Y$. we must  show that $\pi_1(C)$ is closed , or equivalently that its  complement  is open.For  any $x \in X -\pi_1(C)$ , $\{x\} \times Y$ is contained in $U$.By the  the  tube lemma applied to the **open set**  $X \times Y- C$there exist an open set $V \subset X$ such that  $x \in V$ and$ V \times Y \subset  X \times Y-C$. If there a point  $w \in V \cap \pi_1(C)$,then for some $y \in Y$ , we would have  $w \times y \in C $, a contraction

**My confusion**  : What is $\pi_1(C)$? . Is $\pi_1(C)$   constant or nonconstant function ?

**My thinking** :

If  $C$ is closed interval, then $\pi_1(C) \implies \pi_1 $  may be non-constant/constant that depend upon the  function

Here  i don't  know what type of function is taken in the proof .

Comment: $\pi_1(C)$ is just the image of $C$ (that is, $\{ \pi_1 (c) : c\in C\}$).

Comment: okay@ArcticChar  but $\pi_1(c)= ?$

Comment: If $f:A\to B$ and $C\subseteq A,$ $f(C)$ is the image of $C.$ Formally:  $$f(C)=\{b\in B\mid \exists a\in C(b=f(a))\}$$ In particular $f(C)$ is a subset of $B.$

Comment: $C$ is a subset of $X\times Y$ and $\pi _1 : X\times Y\to X$ is a map. $c$ is any elements in $C$.

Comment: And $\pi_1:X\times Y\to X$ is the function $(x,y)\mapsto x.$

Comment: okay @ThomasAndrews that means $\pi_1(C)=C$  Am i right ?

Comment: No, $C\subseteq X\times Y,$ $\pi_1(C)\subseteq X.$ How can they be the same thing?

Comment: you are right @ThomasAndrews But  i still  confuse  about the value of  $\pi_1(C)$

Comment: Example: If $X=\mathbb R$ and $Y=\mathbb R^2,$ and $C=\{(x,(y,z))\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\},$ then $C$ is a sphere of radius $1,$ and $\pi_{1}(C)=[-1,1].$

Comment: That is a nice example@ThomasAndrews Now ,i got some hint